# grouping and counting occurrence values in a collection MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

hope you are well. I am trying to make a graph from my collection but I've run into an issue. How can I group the locations and then count the number of locations in the collection? so for the example below I have 5 kids, I want to know all their locations and how many kids share the same locations, (A = 2, B = 2, and C = 1) that way I can plot Location vs the number of kids in that location. So to summarize, what locations are there and how many kids in each location.

```
"name": "Tom",
 "location": "A'
 
 "name": "Sarah",
 "location": "B'
 
 "name": "Jane",
 "location": "C'
 
 "name": "HIllary",
 "location": "A'
 
 "name": "Mat",
 "location": "B'
```

Edit here is my code

```
router.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
    
    const locations  = Kids.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          continent: "$locations",
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    }
])
    
    locations.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(`${item._id.province} num of kids is: ${item.count}`);
 });
        
    res.render('contact');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.kids.aggregate([ {$group:{_id:"$location" , count:{$sum:1}  }    }     ])
```

Comment: thank you when i log the result i get
` {"_pipeline":[{"$group":{"_id":"$location","count":{"$sum":1}}}],"options":{}} `
and when i log it as a string i get
` Aggregate {
  _pipeline: [ { '$group': [Object] } ],
  _model: Model { Kids },
  options: {} } `
 im not sure what to do next.

Comment: this is what i did:
var locations =  Kids.aggregate([ {$group:{_id:"$location" , count:{$sum:1}  }    }     ]);
then i log:
console.log(locations);

Comment: The aggregate returns A cursor to the documents produced by the final stage of the aggregation pipeline operation. You could use `count()` on the cursor.

Comment: @EzraSiton when i do that i get the same result:
[object Object] this is what im getting now

Comment: try printjson(locations)

Answer (score 0):

"The logic" (What to do with the values) not related to the steps (Store the values in `variables` and do "something").

### HOW TO (OUTLINE)

**Example - Simple countries collection group by continents** using [compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)
(Great to use `compass` to learn this topic).

**Our data** (4 countries: Italy, England, Nigeria, Brazil, and their continents).

[image]

### Step 1/3 - explore your aggregate

Output 3 groups (Europe (count 2), Africa (1), South America (1))

```
{
  _id: {
    continent: "$continent"
  },
  count: {
  $sum: 1,
  }
}
```

[image]

### Step 2/3 - export code

From GUI to code

**export**
[image]

<kbd>copy paste</kbd>
[image]

#### Step 3/3 - aggregate() method & cursoer.forEach()

The related code (Assuming you connect a MongoDB instance using node [Connection Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/connection))

```
const aggregate_cursor  = db.collection("test_listing").aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          continent: "$continent",
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    }
])
```

And loop throw the cursor:

```
  aggregate_cursor .forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(`${item._id.continent} num of countries is: ${item.count}`);
 });
```

Output:

[image]

#### Related docs:

- **aggregation**: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/
- **cursor.forEach**: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Comment: Thank so much or the detailed answer, i even read the docs as well but im getting this:
locations.forEach is not a function im not sure what im doing wrong. i have posted my entire route in the question.